# Ionic cordova keyboard accessory bar overlaping with keyboard in iPhone X when we open Timepicker

Tags: ionic-framework, iphone-x, ios11.2

I'm facing UI related issue with iPhone X in ionic framework app.
Above issue occurs when we use <input type="time"/> in our app. I have attached screenshot of app where you can clearly see that keyboard is overlapin g with accessory bar. You can 
[Find Screenshot by clicking this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fnvxf.png)

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a bug with WKWebView on iPhone X, rather than being specific to Ionic/Cordova, since it can be reproduced in Safari on iPhone X:

- Open a web page in Safari on iPhone X which contains `<input type="time"/>`

  - e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time
- Select the input
- Observe the native time picker widget exhibits this issue:

[image]

I've submitted a bug report to Apple which details this:

https://openradar.appspot.com/36436978